# Add months and days to year

Tags: r, date

I have a data frame in which a variable contains dates with different formats:

```
1970-01-09
1974
1970
1987-05-28
1970-06-01
1980
```

I would like to add "01-01" to all the dates where I only have the year available in order to have the same format for every date.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Something like: `ifelse(nchar(x) == 4, paste(x, "01-01", sep = "-"), x)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using *anytime* package:

```
library(anytime)

x <- c("1970-01-09","1974","1970","1987-05-28","1970-06-01","1980")
anydate(x)
# [1] "1970-01-09" "1974-01-01" "1970-01-01" "1987-05-28" "1970-06-01" "1980-01-01"
```

Or use *paste*:

```
ifelse(nchar(x) == 4, paste(x, "01-01", sep = "-"), x)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to use the paste option. However, I have an error when running the code (my x variable is a factor):

> ifelse(nchar(x) == 4, paste(x, "01-01", sep = "-"), x)
Error in nchar(x) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector

Ideas on how to remediate to this?

Comment: @AshlingMcPhillips use as.character(x)